# ¿Por qué se usa el verbo "poder" en subjuntivo en esta frase?

Tags: subjuntivo

Estoy leyendo "Articuentos" de Juan José Millás para mejorar mi español. No entiendo la frase siguente:

> El único que podría comprarme soy yo, y no porque no **pueda** vivir sin mí, sino por lástima.

¿Por qué se usa el verbo "poder" en subjuntivo aquí? No es por "influencia" o "incertidumbre", entonces no entiendo el uso aquí.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! La explicación más sencilla suele ser la correcta. El subjuntivo sirve, en primer lugar, para expresar opiniones subjetivas. Si dijera "porque no puedo vivir sin mí", está diciendo que, efectivamente, no puede vivir sin él. Al usar el subjuntivo lo expresa como una opinión personal. Te recomendamos que le eches un vistazo a otras preguntas marcadas con la etiqueta "subjuntivo", posiblemente alguna se ajuste a lo que buscas. Si no, dinos qué hace a esta pregunta especial. Cuanto más nos cuentes, mejor.

Answer (score 1):

El subjuntivo se usa, *grosso modo*, para cualquier cosa que no sean "hechos".

Si no usara subjuntivo, el autor estaría **afirmando** el hecho de "no poder vivir sin él mismo". Al usar el subjuntivo, habla de esa situación sin afirmar que sea cierta.

Ejemplo explícito:

No porque no puedo vivir sin mí, sino ...  = "Not because I cannot live without myself, (which is also true), but..."

vs.

No porque no pueda vivir sin mí, sino... = "Not because I couldn't live without me (which is not the case), but ...".